# how to get the data in dataset in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

im trying to get the data from the database. in the first loop it can get the data but in the second loop it will pop up a error saying:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

heres my code:

```
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT refno, pono FROM transmital WHERE refname = '" & txtTransRefName.Text & "' ORDER BY refno", DB.DARConString)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "refnam")

        xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()

        For i = 0 To ds.Tables("refnam").Rows.Count - 1

            **'this line gets the error** refnum = ds.Tables("refnam").Rows(i).Item("refno").ToString.Trim
            ponum = ds.Tables("refnam").Rows(i).Item("pono").ToString.Trim
        Next
```

any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Which line throws the exception? That'll lead you to the cause.

Comment: at the refnum = ds.Tables("refnam").Rows(i).Item("refno").ToString.Trim

Comment: Then either Tables("refnam") is nothing, Rows(i) is nothing or Item("refno") is nothing.... should be fairly easy to debug and see which.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i have already know the cause of the error .. btw thanks

Answer (score 1):

looking at your code, seems that you are trying to get data from "refnam" table, right? then, what is "transmital"? your DB Name?

```
da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT refno, pono FROM transmital WHERE refname = '" & txtTransRefName.Text & "' ORDER BY refno", DB.DARConString)
            ds = New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds, "refnam")
```

your queryString should looks like as "SELECT refno, pono FROM refnam ..."

```
    Dim Adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, SQLConn)
                Dim ds As New DataSet()
                Adpt.Fill(ds, "refnam")
    MyDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

If you would like to present results on a datagridView before saving to xls, datagridView.columns.clear or non previous set columns are necessary.